# How do I create a Temporary Table for Returning?

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2000

I'm building a stored procedure that will serve as a **Configuration String** code reader that will take a `@config varchar(255)` variable.

This **Configuration String** determines 26 settings in our model.

Take one of the Configuration String entries:

```
declare @casingType varchar(50);
set @casingType=case SubString(@config, 34, 1)
  when '1' then 'U-Flange - All Around w/ Stacking Flanges'
  when '2' then 'U-Flange - All Around'
  when '3' then 'U-Flange - No Top & Bottom'
  when '4' then 'U-Flange - Flat Top & Bottom'
  when '5' then 'Box Bracket - End Plates Only'
  when '6' then 'Box Bracket - All Around'
  when '7' then 'Slip & Drive Bracket'
  when '8' then 'L Flange'
  when '0' then 'No Casing'
  when 'A' then '3 Sided Box - No Top & Bottom'
  when 'B' then '3 Sided Box - Top & Bottom'
  when 'C' then '3 Sided Box - Top or Bottom'
  when 'D' then 'U-Flange w/ Stacking Plates'
  when 'E' then 'U-Flange Temp Top & Bottom'
  when 'F' then 'Flat Bracket'
  when 'G' then 'A Coil Slab Bracket'
  when 'H' then '2 Sided Box'
  when 'I' then '3 Sided Box w/ Temp Top & Bottom'
  when 'O' then 'One Plus One Casing'
  when 'X' then 'Special'
  when 'Y' then 'Auto Braze'
  else 'Error' end;
```

What I want to return is a table of one (1) row containing the text fields of each item.

Do I create a temporary table to return or create some other type of table to return?

I hope this makes sense. It is possible that I worded it incorrectly or used inappropriate SQL jargon.

**Solution:** So, I got this to work, and here is the code I used to do it.

Often our Sales guys or Engineers working from the **Configuration String** do not know what a certain letter means, so they have to look it up. Over 70% of the time, this results in more letter code searches. So, we want to simply return all of the details associated with a particular configuration.

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
-- =============================================
-- Author:      Joe Pool
-- Create date: 21-22 January 2013
-- Description: This returns a DataTable representation of the Model Configuration
-- =============================================
CREATE PROCEDURE sp1_Configurator(@config varchar(255)) as
BEGIN
SET NOCOUNT ON;
declare @len int;
declare @coilType varchar(50), @coilPattern varchar(50), @rowsDeep varchar(50);
declare @finHeight varchar(50), @finLength varchar(50), @finThickMat varchar(50);
declare @finPerInch varchar(50), @finTreatment varchar(50), @finCoating varchar(50);
declare @tubeWallThk varchar(50), @tubeType varchar(50), @qty varchar(50);
declare @tubeCoat varchar(50), @gauge varchar(50), @material varchar(50);
declare @casingType varchar(50), @customerCode varchar(50), @caseCoat varchar(50);
declare @arrangement varchar(50), @connType varchar(50), @connSize varchar(50);
declare @distributor varchar(50), @circuitry varchar(50), @coilApp varchar(50);
declare @agency varchar(50), @outsideCoat varchar(50);
declare @table table (
  CoilType varchar(50) null, CoilPattern varchar(50) null, RowsDeep varchar(50) null, 
  FinHeight varchar(50) null, FinLength varchar(50) null, FinThickMat varchar(50) null, 
  FinPerInch varchar(50) null, FinTreatment varchar(50) null, FinCoating varchar(50) null, 
  TubeWallThk varchar(50) null, TubeType varchar(50) null, Qty varchar(50) null, 
  TubeCoat varchar(50) null, Gauge varchar(50) null, Material varchar(50) null, 
  CasingType varchar(50) null, CustomerCode varchar(50) null, CaseCoat varchar(50) null, 
  Arrangement varchar(50) null, ConnType varchar(50) null, ConnSize varchar(50) null, 
  Distributor varchar(50) null, Circuitry varchar(50) null, CoilApp varchar(50) null, 
  Agency varchar(50) null, OutsideCoat varchar(50) null
);
set @len=Len(@config)
if (@len=53) begin
  set @coilType=case SubString(@config, 1, 1)
    when 'C' then 'Slab' 
    when 'B' then '1 + 1'
    when 'A' then 'A Coil (OBS)'
    when 'X' then 'Special'
    else 'Error' end;
  set @coilPattern=case SubString(@config, 2, 1)
    when '7' then '7mm Tube (.827 x .472 Staggered)'
    when '6' then '5/16" Tube (1 x 5/8 Staggered)(OBS)'
    when '3' then '3/8" Tube (1 x .866 Staggered)'
    when 'P' then '1/2" Tube (1 1/4 x 1.08 Staggered)'
    when '5' then '5/8" Tube (1 1/2 x 1.299 Staggered)'
    else 'Error' end;
  set @rowsDeep=SubString(@config, 3, 2);
  set @finHeight=SubString(@config, 6, 5);
  set @finLength=SubString(@config, 12, 6);
  set @finThickMat=case SubString(@config, 19, 1)
    when 'A' then '.0045 AL (OBS)'
    when 'J' then '.0055 AL (OBS)'
    when 'B' then '.0060 AL'
    when 'C' then '.0075 AL'
    when 'D' then '.0100 AL'
    when 'E' then '.0045 CU (OBS)'
    when 'K' then '.0050 CU (OBS)'
    when 'F' then '.0060 CU'
    when 'G' then '.0075 CU (OBS)'
    when 'H' then '.0100 CU (OBS)'
    when 'P' then '.0065 Pre-Coated'
    when 'X' then 'Special'
    else 'Error' end;
  set @finPerInch=SubString(@config, 20, 2);
  set @finTreatment=case SubString(@config, 22, 2)
    when 'FS' then 'Flat / Straight (OBS)'
    when 'FR' then 'Flat / Rippled (OBS)'
    when 'CS' then 'Corrugated / Straight (OBS)'
    when 'CR' then 'Corrugated / Rippled'
    when 'SS' then 'Sine / Straight (OBS)'
    when 'SR' then 'Sine / Rippled'
    when 'LS' then 'Louvered / Straight (OBS)'
    when 'LR' then 'Louvered / Rippled (OBS)'
    when 'RL' then 'Embossed Arch / Rippled*'
    when 'XX' then 'Special'
    else 'Error' end;
  set @finCoating=case SubString(@config, 24, 1)
    when 'N' then 'See Coil Coating'
    when 'A' then 'Alodine (OBS)'
    when 'K' then 'Technicoat'
    when 'P' then 'Paint Bond'
    when 'X' then 'Special'
    else 'Error' end;
  set @tubeWallThk=case SubString(@config, 26, 1)
    when 'A' then '.012 Smooth (5/16)(OBS)'
    when 'B' then '.014 Smooth (3/8)(OBS)'
    when 'C' then '.017 Smooth (1/2)'
    when 'D' then '.018 Smooth (5/8)'
    when 'E' then '.025 Smooth (1/2, 5/8)'
    when 'F' then '.035 Smooth (1/2, 5/8)'
    when 'G' then '.049 Smooth (5/8)'
    when 'H' then '.012 Rifled (3/8)'
    when 'K' then '.012 Rifled (7mm)'
    when 'L' then '.016 Rifled (7mm) (OBS)'
    when 'P' then '.06 Rifled (1/2)'
    when 'X' then 'Special (.016 Rifled 3/8)(OBS)'
    else 'Error' end;
  set @tubeType=case SubString(@config, 27, 1)
    when '1' then 'ST Flexpand'
    when '2' then 'ST ALL DL Flexpand'
    when '3' then 'ST w/DLST Flexpand'
    when '5' then 'HP Flexpand'
    when '6' then 'HP w/ST Flexpand'
    when 'A' then 'ST w/DL*'
    when 'B' then 'HP w/DL*'
    when 'C' then 'Hairpin w/Straight*'
    when 'D' then 'Hairpin 1/Hairpin .8* (OB)'
    when 'E' then 'HP / DL / ST*'
    when 'F' then 'HP / DL / ST / ST DL*'
    when 'G' then 'HP / DL ST*'
    when 'H' then 'Hairpint (HP)'
    when 'I' then 'HP / ST / DL HP*'
    when 'J' then '.8 HP* (OBS)'
    when 'K' then 'One Short HP / One Long HP*'
    when 'L' then 'HP w/Special DL*'
    when 'M' then 'HP w/Special DL / ST*'
    when 'N' then 'HP 1/HP .8/ST* (OBS)'
    when 'O' then 'HP 1/HP .8/DL 1 HP/DL .8 HP* (OBS)'
    when 'P' then 'All DL ST'
    when 'Q' then 'ST w/Special DL ST*'
    when 'R' then 'HP .8 / ST* (OBS)'
    when 'S' then 'Straight (ST)'
    when 'T' then 'Hydro Ball (HB)'
    when 'U' then 'HB w/ DL*'
    when 'V' then 'ST w/Spin Down*'
    when 'W' then 'HP 7mm .827/.627 Angle*'
    when 'Y' then 'HP 7mm All .627*'
    when 'X' then 'Special*'
    else 'Error' end;
  set @qty=SubString(@config, 28, 2);
  set @tubeCoat=case SubString(@config, 30, 1)
    when 'N' then 'No Coating'
    when 'T' then 'Tinned Plating (OBS)'
    when 'X' then 'Special'
    else 'Error' end;
  set @gauge=case SubString(@config, 32, 1)
    when '2' then '20 Gauge'
    when '8' then '18 Gauge'
    when '6' then '16 Gauge'
    when '4' then '14 Gauge'
    when '5' then '0.050" THK'
    when '3' then '0.063" THK'
    when '9' then '0.090" THK'
    when 'X' then 'Special'
    else 'Error' end;
  set @material=case SubString(@config, 33, 1)
    when 'G' then 'Galvanized'
    when 'S' then 'Stainless'
    when 'C' then 'Copper'
    when 'A' then 'Aluminum'
    when 'P' then 'Paint Bond'
    when 'X' then 'Special'
    else 'Error' end;
  set @casingType=case SubString(@config, 34, 1)
    when '1' then 'U-Flange - All Around w/ Stacking Flanges'
    when '2' then 'U-Flange - All Around'
    when '3' then 'U-Flange - No Top & Bottom'
    when '4' then 'U-Flange - Flat Top & Bottom'
    when '5' then 'Box Bracket - End Plates Only'
    when '6' then 'Box Bracket - All Around'
    when '7' then 'Slip & Drive Bracket'
    when '8' then 'L Flange'
    when '0' then 'No Casing'
    when 'A' then '3 Sided Box - No Top & Bottom'
    when 'B' then '3 Sided Box - Top & Bottom'
    when 'C' then '3 Sided Box - Top or Bottom'
    when 'D' then 'U-Flange w/ Stacking Plates'
    when 'E' then 'U-Flange Temp Top & Bottom'
    when 'F' then 'Flat Bracket'
    when 'G' then 'A Coil Slab Bracket'
    when 'H' then '2 Sided Box'
    when 'I' then '3 Sided Box w/ Temp Top & Bottom'
    when 'O' then 'One Plus One Casing'
    when 'X' then 'Special'
    when 'Y' then 'Auto Braze'
    else 'Error' end;
  set @customerCode=case SubString(@config, 35, 5)
    when '00' then 'Standard'
    when '14' then 'AAON Damper'
    when '15' then 'AAON Cond.'
    when '16' then 'AAON Evap.'
    when 'XX' then 'Special'
    else 'Error' end;
  set @caseCoat=case SubString(@config, 37, 1)
    when 'N' then 'See Coil Coating'
    when 'A' then 'Alodine (OBS)'
    when 'C' then 'Ceramic'
    when 'X' then 'Special'
    else 'Error' end;
  set @arrangement=SubString(@config, 39, 2);
  set @connType=case SubString(@config, 41, 1)
    when '0' then 'No Connection'
    when 'M' then 'MPT'
    when 'F' then 'FPT'
    when 'S' then 'Sweat'
    when 'W' then 'Water Bead (OBS)'
    when 'B' then 'Barbed FTG (OBS)'
    when 'N' then 'Male Flare'
    when 'G' then 'Female Flare'
    when 'O' then 'Male O-Ring (OBS)'
    when 'P' then 'Female O-Ring (OBS)'
    when 'X' then 'Special'
    else 'Error' end;
  set @connSize=case SubString(@config, 42, 1)
    when '0' then 'No Connection'
    when '1' then '3/8 OD'
    when '2' then '1/2 OD'
    when '3' then '5/8 OD'
    when '4' then '7/8 OD'
    when '5' then '1-1/8 OD'
    when '6' then '1-3/8 OD'
    when '7' then '1-5/8 OD'
    when '8' then '2-1/8 OD'
    when '9' then '2-5/8 OD'
    when 'A' then '3-1/8 OD'
    when 'B' then '5/16 OD'
    when 'C' then '3/4 OD'
    when 'D' then '4-1/8 OD'
    when 'E' then '3/16 OD'
    when 'X' then 'Special'
    else 'Error' end;
  set @distributor=case SubString(@config, 44, 4)
    when 'N000' then 'None Required'
    when 'X001' then 'Special'
    else 'Factory Assigned' end;
  set @circuitry=case SubString(@config, 49, 2)
    when 'SS' then 'Single Circuit'
    when 'FF' then 'Full'
    when 'HH' then 'Half'
    when 'QQ' then 'Quarter'
    when 'DD' then 'Double'
    when 'DH' then '1-1/2'
    when 'II' then 'Intertwined <2'
    when 'RS' then 'Row Split <2'
    when 'FS' then 'Face Split <2'
    when '00' then 'No Circuitry'
    when '01' then 'One Circuit'
    when '02' then 'Two Circuits'
    when '03' then 'Three Circuits'
    when '04' then 'Four Circuits'
    when '0S' then 'No Circuitry + SubCooler'
    when '1S' then 'One Circuit + SubCooler'
    when '2S' then 'Two Circuits + SubCooler'
    when '3S' then 'Three Circuits + SubCooler'
    when 'XX' then 'Special'
    else 'Error' end;
  set @coilApp=case SubString(@config, 51, 1)
    when 'D' then 'Drainable Water'
    when 'W' then 'Water'
    when 'G' then 'Cond / SubCooler'
    when 'C' then 'Condenser'
    when 'E' then 'Evaporator'
    when 'S' then 'Steam'
    when 'N' then 'Steam Distributor'
    when 'B' then 'Booster'
    when 'H' then 'Heat Reclaim'
    when 'P' then 'Heat Pipe (OBS)'
    when 'L' then 'Glycol'
    when 'O' then 'Oil (OBS)'
    when 'X' then 'Special'
    else 'Error' end;
  set @agency=case SubString(@config, 52, 1)
    when '0' then 'None'
    when 'A' then 'ARI'
    when 'B' then 'ARI + UL / CSA'
    when 'C' then 'UL / CSA'
    when 'E' then 'ETL / DOE'
    else 'Error' end;
  set @outsideCoat=case SubString(@config, 53, 1)
    when 'N' then 'No Coating'
    when 'A' then 'Ceramic'
    when 'C' then 'Chromocoat'
    when 'E' then 'Epoxy'
    when 'G' then 'Americoat Grey (OBS)'
    when 'H' then 'Heresite'
    when 'K' then 'Phenolic (Technicoat)'
    when 'L' then 'ElectroFin'
    when 'P' then 'Phenolic (OBS)'
    when 'X' then 'Special'
    else 'Error' end;
  insert into @table
    (CoilType, CoilPattern, RowsDeep, FinHeight, FinLength, FinThickMat, FinPerInch, FinTreatment, FinCoating,
     TubeWallThk, TubeType, Qty, TubeCoat, Gauge, Material, CasingType, CustomerCode, CaseCoat, Arrangement,
     ConnType, ConnSize, Distributor, Circuitry, CoilApp, Agency, OutsideCoat)
     values
    (@coilType, @coilPattern, @rowsDeep, @finHeight, @finLength, @finThickMat, @finPerInch, @finTreatment, @finCoating,
    @tubeWallThk, @tubeType, @qty, @tubeCoat, @gauge, @material, @casingType, @customerCode, @caseCoat, @arrangement,
    @connType, @connSize, @distributor, @circuitry, @coilApp, @agency, @outsideCoat);
end
select * from @table;
END
GO
```

Here is what an actual **Configuration String** looks like:

> CP06-51.25-051.50-B12SRN-CT00N-8G2XXN-A2S8-N000-HHWAN

Comment: Can you describe what you need to do with this table, show what you want the output to look like, and show sample data so we have some idea what "text fields of each item" means?

Comment: I just want our developers to be able to pull the info off our server and get the data by column name. By putting this on the server in the database, we can make quick changes as the models change.

Comment: Sorry, I don't think that answers my question at all. Oh well, hope bluefeet's answer works for you. <shrug>

Comment: Aaron, I updated the question with the solution. This is just a look-up table and is not tied to any particular database. I hope that helps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you thought about creating a user-defined function:

```
create function CastingTypeFunction(@config varchar(255))
returns varchar(50)
as
begin
  declare @casingType varchar(50)
  set @casingType=case SubString(@config, 34, 1)
    when '1' then 'U-Flange - All Around w/ Stacking Flanges'
    when '2' then 'U-Flange - All Around'
    when '3' then 'U-Flange - No Top & Bottom'
    when '4' then 'U-Flange - Flat Top & Bottom'
    when '5' then 'Box Bracket - End Plates Only'
    when '6' then 'Box Bracket - All Around'
    when '7' then 'Slip & Drive Bracket'
    when '8' then 'L Flange'
    when '0' then 'No Casing'
    when 'A' then '3 Sided Box - No Top & Bottom'
    when 'B' then '3 Sided Box - Top & Bottom'
    when 'C' then '3 Sided Box - Top or Bottom'
    when 'D' then 'U-Flange w/ Stacking Plates'
    when 'E' then 'U-Flange Temp Top & Bottom'
    when 'F' then 'Flat Bracket'
    when 'G' then 'A Coil Slab Bracket'
    when 'H' then '2 Sided Box'
    when 'I' then '3 Sided Box w/ Temp Top & Bottom'
    when 'O' then 'One Plus One Casing'
    when 'X' then 'Special'
    when 'Y' then 'Auto Braze'
    else 'Error' end

    return @casingType
end;
```

You will then pass your `@config` value into the function similar to this:

```
 select dbo.CastingTypeFunction(@config)
```

Your value will then be returned.

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/f8e6e/3).

The other option that I can see that you have is to create a table that contains each of these values and you would join on that table to return the `casingType`.

The tables would be similar to this:

```
CREATE TABLE CasingType
    ([CasingTypeId] varchar(1), [CasingValue] varchar(41))
;
```

And then you would join it similar to this:

```
select 
  case 
    when c.casingtypeid is null 
    then 'Error'
    else c.casingvalue end
from
(
  select '12323212334234231211231212121qwe1212312334234234' config  -- replace with your config values
) src
left join CasingType c
  on SubString(src.config, 34, 1) = c.casingtypeid
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/ed375/2)

Comment: could you tell why you chose the select-case-syntax in the last query? Personal preference? What about `isnull( c.casingvalue , 'Error' )` instead? Thanks!

Comment: @Nico I just wrote it that way, you can also use coalesce, etc to check for null.

Comment: That's probably what I'm wanting to do. I just wasn't sure if I needed to create this into a temporary table #CastingType or if I should delete the table after selecting the data from it.

Comment: @jp2code If you are going to do this type of conversion more than once, then I would consider using either a function or the table.

Comment: So, I updated my original question with the solution I used. What I wanted was `declare @table table (...);` I stumbled upon that while looking for a better way. So, given my solution, would it work any better or the same if I changed it from a Procedure to a Function? Should a Function return a Table?

Comment: @jp2code since your list of transformations is so long, you might be able to use a function that returns a single value which is the `casingType`, similar to my first version